# Does a native speaker pronounce spatial and special differently?

Tags: differences, pronunciation

I'm attending a university course on spatial reasoning in computational systems. So the word spatial is often spoken here.
The Germans in the course usually speak English slowly and more carefully so that I can hear an obvious difference between the two words spatial and special. But the English native speakers here, who talk a lot faster, don't seem to make a difference between the words.

Am I just unable to hear the difference because I'm not used to it or do they really make no difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only flavor of English in which *special* and *spatial* are homophones is in a rural, uneducated [Inland/Mountain South](https://books.google.de/books?id=tgf_NwVtDlUC&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=special%20pronounced%20as%20spatial%20American%20dialect&source=bl&ots=snS9rtQgS4&sig=gEatwAIJT8ymbwoxadCfRRB6T7s&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAjJ636MjZAhVEblAKHTnvDcgQ6AEwCnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=special%20pronounced%20as%20spatial%20American%20dialect&f=false) accent which can be heard from southern Ohio through Kentucky, Tennessee, western North Carolina and into Arkansas and Texas.

Otherwise, *special* is pronounced with a short e as in DRESS and *spatial* with a long a as in FACE.